# Excel VBA CSV export with to many semicolons

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel VBA to calculate dimensions for storage locations in a warehouse. The results are send via CSV to storage machines so that they know how much product can fit in a storage container.

It worked like a charm but now after some finetuning there is a problem.

Firts is the product identifier.
In the second column you see 1 to 10. Thats ten different storage containers.
Then a minimal amount and then a maximum amount for that storage container.

It looks like this:

```
000165025W;1;0;;;;;;;;;
000165025W;2;100;1;;;;;;;;
000165025W;3;0;;;;;;;;;
000165025W;4;300;101;;;;;;;;
000165025W;5;450;301;;;;;;;;
000165025W;6;0;;;;;;;;;
000165025W;7;0;;;;;;;;;
000165025W;8;900;451;;;;;;;;
000165025W;9;1725;901;;;;;;;;
000165025W;10;0;;;;;;;;;
```

Should look like this:

```
000165025W;1;0;
000165025W;2;100;1;
000165025W;3;0;
000165025W;4;300;101;
000165025W;5;450;301;
000165025W;6;0;
000165025W;7;0;
000165025W;8;900;451;
000165025W;9;1725;901;
000165025W;10;0;
```

Is there a way to lose all the semicolons or does anyone know whats causing this?

This is the piece of code that is responsible for creating the csv's..

```
Sheets("NIEUW").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("1:32").EntireRow.Delete 
ActiveSheet.Range("43:1000").EntireRow.Delete 
ActiveSheet.Range("E:Z").EntireColumn.Delete   

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
With ActiveWorkbook 

  .SaveAs Filename:=MijnPad & MijnBestandsNaam, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
 .SaveAs Filename:=MijnPad2 & MijnBestandsNaam2, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True      .Close False
 End With
```

Thanks a lot!

I added a lot of code to existing (working) code.

Comment: [ask] specifically says to not use screenshots of code/data/errors. Please  [edit] your question with the code and data *as text*.

Comment: This means that your workbook has 11 columns. I mean, in the eleventh column there is a space or something else. You cannot **`saveAs`** CSV (in this way) with different number of columns **per row**.

Comment: After saving the file, you can [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) it back up for I/O (see the examples in the article) and, line-by-line, remove any excess semi-colons. See these two articles on [Reading lines from a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-inputstatement) and [writing to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement).

Comment: @zanderr021, welcome to stack overflow.  If the answer below is helpful, you should mark it as the accepeted answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there are blank cells on the sheet that you are copying from.  Try changing

```
activesheet.range("E:Z").entirecolumn.delete
```

to

```
activesheet.range("E:XFD").entirecolumn.delete
```

or, more simply

```
activesheet.range("E:XFD").delete
```

This should get rid of any columns after the first 4, the ones with your data

Comment: It didn't work! I already tried that, tried it again just now.. The Semicolons are still there..

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything else.